# How to rightclick on selected telerik radtreeview node in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, telerik, treeview

Below is the code i implemented, but it is not working

```
Random r=new Random();

WebElement treeview = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_RadTreeView1"));

List<WebElement> treeviewList1 = treeview.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rtIn.myReportNode"));   
WebElement MyReportNode=treeviewList1.get(r.nextInt(treeviewList1.size()));

Actions action= new Actions(driver);         
action.contextClick(MyReportNode);

action.build().perform();
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: action.contextClick(MyReportNode) this one is not any performing action.

Comment: MyReportNode is listitem in a radtreeview with in a div.

Comment: Have you tried stringing the build and perform into one, like this:-

    `action.contextClick(MyReportNode).build().perform();`

Comment: Yes I tried ..but still it is not working.